# Pixel tracking to BQ: how to save querystring parameter values directly to BQ table fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I was setting up a serverless tracking pixel using this article: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/serverless-pixel-tracking-tutorial

This works but saves the entire pixel GET URL into one single field in BQ - as the pixel URL will carry multiple querystring paramter values with it and best is that these go into individual fields in BQ: I want to tweak it to save each querystring parameter value of the GET tracking pixel into its own BQ table field.

Assuming the names and number of the querystring parameters are known and they match 1-to-1 to the BQ table columns - what would be the recommended way to achieve this?

I was looking in the article if the logs query can be tuned to do this.
Also I saw that Dataflow may be the way to go but thinking if it is possible in a more direct & simple way.

Answer (score 0):

The simple direct way is to create a query in BigQuery that will expose them into columns.
You can have this query first as a VIEW and you can query the view instead of the full query.

Then you can setup a scheduled query in BigQuery to run this query regularly and save into a new table. This way you have the old table getting the links as it is. The scheduler that will create a new table.

You can tune to remove existing rows from the incoming table, and append new rows to the materialized table.

Comment: This would work but not be best in terms of cost and speed. 
more background info: 
this tracking pixel will get in huge amount of requests and the data should be available almost in real-time for report-queries.

For the above solution we will have to run the scheduled query very often, every 1 minute lets say, this will have 2 downsides:
1. cost: query will minimum read data for that column for all that day (if is partitioned) and discard most of what is read, use only new-inserted rows
2. quota: we have to run 1440 insert queries by day, max is 1000
a streaming solution is possible?

Comment: Oh, for high throughput you can use use Pub/Sub and Dataflow to BigQuery, this way you can have a high speed, up to 1M/rows per sec.